# php slim framework response wait issue

Tags: php, apache, slim-3

I developed an API using a the Slim framework. On JavaScript side two APIs are called asynchronously. One call is taking too much time and one takes less. But the response is coming after the one that takes long ends.

Is any issue related slim response object wait issue?

Answer (score 0):

Slim is not the issue here. Maybe have a deeper look into your code or the services you belong to.